# Awaiting data from Xamarin/MAUI IOS Healthkit query

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, maui, healthkit

I'm not familiar with threads, awaiting and delegates etc. I have the following problem. This method:

```
public HKSample[] Get(DateTime from, DateTime? to)
    {
        HKSample[] result = null;

        var restingHeartRateType = HKQuantityType.Create(HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.RestingHeartRate);

        var predicate = HKQuery.GetPredicateForSamples(from.ToNSDate(), to.HasValue ? to.Value.ToNSDate() : null, HKQueryOptions.None);

        var q = new HKSampleQuery(
            restingHeartRateType,
            predicate,
            500,
            new NSSortDescriptor[] { },
            new HKSampleQueryResultsHandler(
                (HKSampleQuery query2, HKSample[] results, NSError error2) =>
            {
                result = results;
            }));

        healthKitStore.ExecuteQuery(q);

        return result;
    }
```

returns before the resultshandler sets the method return variable. How can I wait for the result variable to be set before finishing the method?

I'm doing a lot of healthkit investigation, I'm shocked at how little is sampled / documented for xamarin/maui c#.

Comment: if the query is executing asynchronously, then your code can't block and return a result.  There are a lot of patterns for handling this - the simplest might be to raise an event when the query completes

Answer (score 0):

In general, if a task or function takes a long time, we generally recommend executing code asynchronously. Otherwise, the program is prone to crash or blocked.

If you want to wait for a function to finish before performing subsequent operations, you can use `Async and await` to do so.

Please refer to the following code:

```
   async void callMethod() { 

        Task<HKSample[]> task = Get(from, to);

        HKSample[] hKs  = await task;

    }

    public async  Task<HKSample[]>  Get(DateTime from, DateTime? to)
    {
        HKSample[] result = null;

        var restingHeartRateType = HKQuantityType.Create(HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.RestingHeartRate);

        var predicate = HKQuery.GetPredicateForSamples(from.ToNSDate(), to.HasValue ? to.Value.ToNSDate() : null, HKQueryOptions.None);

        var q = new HKSampleQuery(
            restingHeartRateType,
            predicate,
            500,
            new NSSortDescriptor[] { },
            new HKSampleQueryResultsHandler(
                (HKSampleQuery query2, HKSample[] results, NSError error2) =>
                {
                    result = results;
                }));

        healthKitStore.ExecuteQuery(q);

        return result;
    }
```

For more about async and await, you can check: [Asynchronous programming with Async and Await (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/) and [Async And Await In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/).